# How to get user details when authenticating with social sign in with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am in the middle of creating a Flutter application and am stuck on how to implement authentication using email/password and social providers like Google and Facebook. Everything works except my approach on how to get user details to store in Firebase like address, phone number, username, etc. Implementing this when working with email/password registration has been simple because I created a multi screen form and then finally registered the user which would log them in. The problem with getting additional details when working with social providers is that I would need to authenticate the user first before ever getting the chance to get additional details. How can I go about getting user details for users that choose to use Google and Facebook to authenticate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to prompt the user to enter the required additional details when the user logs in.

You should first check if the user logged in through a Social Media provider :

```
List<String> providerList = await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(_email);
```

**fetchSignInMethodsForEmail** will return a list of sign providers the user used to login to your app (if you haven't enabled account linking, this would probably be just one provider)

Here's a list of social media provider ID's :

```
GoogleAuthProviderID: google.com
FacebookAuthProviderID: facebook.com
TwitterAuthProviderID: twitter.com
GitHubAuthProviderID: github.com
AppleAuthProviderID: apple.com
YahooAuthProviderID: yahoo.com
MicrosoftAuthProviderID: hotmail.com
```

For example, if you have enabled Facebook login, you can check if the 'facebook.com' is available in the **providerList**, if so prompt a screen to collect your additional data and update your user record on Firestore for this user.

Comment: Thanks for this @RamithDR . What do you think a good practice is for when to show the screen to collect the additional details. I would only want that screen to show up if its their first time signing in. Maybe a boolean field on the user document?

Comment: @Beardedblack Yes you can maintain a boolean, make it true when you successfully collect all info and store in the database.

Comment: @Beardedblack consider selecting this as the answer if my answer helped you.